# iTextSharp SetPageSize return true always

Tags: powershell, itext

if someone can tell is this bug or I miss something.

Using this code in PowerShell:

```
$pdf = New-Object iTextSharp.text.Document
$pdf.SetPageSize([iTextSharp.text.PageSize]::A4)
```

returns True which is OK.

This is intentional error, for debugging purposes:

```
$pdf = New-Object iTextSharp.text.Document
$pdf.SetPageSize([iTextSharp.text.PageSize]::DD)
```

returns True which is NOT OK. And also not create any exception.

In second example, PDF is NOT created as next function $pdf.Open() got exception (not related to pagesize).
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a two part problem:

1) The `iTextSharp.text.Document` [source code](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/develop/src/core/iTextSharp/text/Document.cs) confirms `SetPageSize()` **always** returns `true`. Only the developers can answer whether this is intended behavior or a bug. For reference, here's the definition:

```
public virtual bool SetPageSize(Rectangle pageSize)
{
  this.pageSize = pageSize;
  foreach (IDocListener listener in this.listeners)
    listener.SetPageSize(pageSize);
  return true;
}
```

2) PowerShell, unlike .NET, will happily eat invalid `enum` names. In your example:

```
$pageSize = [iTextSharp.text.PageSize]::DD; # $pageSize -eq $null ($true; no Exception / error)
```

In other words, if you need to confirm a valid `PageSize` **in PowerShell**, check using something like above.